# Ant Design Table component onChange callback not fired

Tags: reactjs, antd

The `Table` component from Ant Design has the prop `onChange` which is fired whenever some pagination, filter or sort is happening. In my case it is about filtering. When using the default filter elements from the table head, the callback is fired. But I am using custom filter elements outside of the `Table` component which set a local state and this state  is used for the `filteredValue` prop on the column. The filtering itself works flawless. But the `onChange` callback is not fired. I am interested in the attributes from `onChange` since they contain the `currentDataSource` props which represents the actual rendered data source object.
I can't find any other callbacks for `Table` which are triggered whenever the component renders.

Has anybody an idea about another way to get the rendered dataSource object when filters are enabled? Sure, I could start calculating on the original dataSouruce object because I am aware of the filters, but since `Table` provides the information in genereal I would like to prevent the redundancy.

Update:

See basic example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-antd-styled-template-73yxh
Whenever you use the filter elements in the table head, you see a console.log event (via Table's onChange prop). When you click the button on the bottom, you will see that the filter changes, but the console.log event does not happen.

Comment: Please provide a producible example, refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I want to help you but saying "But the onChange callback is not fired" is not enough, need to see the specific example

Comment: You can add an example with stack snippet as mentioned in the link or use [this template](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-antd-styled-template-n8n96) on codesandbox.

Comment: @DennisVash Added codesandbox example. Thx for helping out.

Comment: I don't think it's possible if it does, you should try doing it with Table's ref.

Comment: "Table's ref"? You mean like ref to the DOM element? That would not help when the table is paginated.

Comment: Check how to use - useRef hook

Comment: In what way would you use the refHook to get the `currentDataSource` prop?
Just to be sure: I am not interested in the `dataSource` prop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The described behaviour is intended. `Table` behaves like a controlled `input` field which also does **not** call `onChange` when external state changes.

In my case I am interested in the `currentDataSource` object, to see how many items the table contains. Which is different then `dataSource` when filters are active.

You can get this value from somewhere else. The `Table`'s `Pagination` has a `showTotal` callback with a signature of `Function(total, range)`. Set this callback and you get the actual total items count whenever the pagination renders.

```
<Table
  dataSource={someData}
  columns={someColumns}
  pagination={{
    showTotal: (total, range) => {
      console.log({ total, range });
    }
  }}
/>
```

Update:

Feedback from Ant Design Team with information about the component behaviour on external state change: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/19415#issuecomment-546182503

Comment: Did you find a way to get the rows or row identifiers that are displayed after your custom filtering applied rather than just counts ?

Comment: Also I saw your issue at https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/19415 - perhaps worth adding a reference to that github.com  issue that in this answer.

Comment: @k1eran No, I did not find/need a way to get the filtered rows. You probably also found these issues on ant-design repo. It links to another which is merged but looking at the docs I can't find any informations about this. https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/10462

Comment: Like you described in the question I too am reluctant to duplicate work/state to calculate what rows are displayed  as it is already in the antd table internally.  BTW my reason for looking at it is I have code reacting to table selections (which has a helpful callback) but I want to know if the selected row list is visible i.e. not filtered out with my programmatic filtering . antd table callbacks are giving me the selected rows fine but not the other part which is disappointing. Maybe there's another way to do this that I have overlooked but I think it's unfortunately an antd limitation.